# Two address name for same server

Tags: networking

I'm completely new to IT. My small company just bought another one and it came with a sever. They used this server for data storage and I need to maintain that capability, but since the server is a mess I would like to completely wipe it clean and install it all over again.

The computers we received are configured to look for some information in a fixed network path, f.e. `\\othercompany\somedata` and that's hardcoded into the programs running in those computers so I cannot change it.

The thing is that I don't want to name my server "othercompany" in my domain, I want the network name of the server to be "MyCompanyServer" so the question is, is there any way to name it that way and at the same time add a (dns resolver)? to "othercompany" so doing `\\MyCompanyServer\somedata` would be exactly as doing `\\othercompany\somedata`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to assign several DNS names to the same fileserver. Most commonly this is done using `CNAME` records. However, for SMB file sharing to work correctly a few more things are needed:

1. Create the actual alias by adding a CNAME record in DNS.
2. If this is a Windows server: To allow aliases when connecting from the server *to itself*, the aliases need to be listed in this Registry value:

   - Key: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0`
   - Value name: `BackConnectionHostNames`
   - Type: REG_MULTI_SZ
   - Data: the aliases, one per line.
3. If Active Directory is in use: To allow secure Kerberos authentication when connecting to aliases from AD-joined computers, the SPNs for those aliases (two for each, one with the bare name, one for the full domain name) must be added to the server's AD account:

   ```
   setspn -S HOST/OTHERCOMPANY MyServerName$
   setspn -S HOST/othercompany.ad.mycorp.com MyServerName$
   ```

   Without this, clients would end up using NTLM authentication, which is generally undesirable.
4. For SMBv1 (NetBIOS), the "DisableStrictNameChecking" Registry key was needed. As far as I know this is no longer needed for modern SMBv3.

I would also suggest not rushing to reinstall an existing server no matter how much of a mess it seems to be. At least, not without imaging it first.

See also:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/accessing-server-locally-with-fqdn-cname-alias-denied
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dns-cname-alias-cannot-access-smb-file-server-share
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/printing/windows-couldnt-connect-printer